# Custom render pass

Tags: python, scripting, opengl

I'm looking to develop a post-render diagnostics overlay and am not quite sure how to go about it.

I can add an opengl overlay to the viewport fine with the SpaceView3D draw_handler_add, but this of course will not show in the renderer.

How can I add this to the render result?

Ideally it would be great to have a custom opengl pass but not sure how to go about that in python.

I know I can just add this to the blender source in C, but I'd like to avoid modifying the source as much as possible in case I decide to distribute the addon.

Thanks!